# why extra space on right side of paragraph?

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I am not sure why my

is showing a space from right side. Here is my simple code

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="splash">

        <div data-role="content">   
            <p class="loading">loading...</p>       
        </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

css

```
#splash {
    background: #9d0104 url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat center 30%;
    background-size: 182px;     
}
#splash .loading {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75%;
    background: #ff0000 url(../images/loading.png) no-repeat center top;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: please let me know ..that you want space on right side of loading message as you have in left side or any thing else.. please spacify about which spacing you are asking

Comment: There's no need to set any block elements width to 100% as non-floated, non-positioned block elements are _always_ as wide as their parent allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set equal margin from both left and right side:

```
#splash .loading { margin:0 20px; }
```

Above sets `20px` margin to left as well as right side.

Or since you are using `absolute` position, you can use `right` property to move it a bit to left to suite your needs eg:

```
#splash .loading { right:10px; }
```